# Is it possible to have windows machine participate part time in a hadoop cluster?

Tags: windows, hadoop

We are running into the need for some map-reduce computation and don't want to built out a dedicated cluster for it just yet.  We do have a lot of Windows machines on our network that are used for development, mail, etc.  It would be great if these machines could participate when they are underutilized.

Is there a way to have machines participate in Hadoop (or a different map-reduce/distributed computation system) when they are idle rather than being a dedicated resource?